# VSTO Outlook: How to get the list of default folders that are shown by default in Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

From an Outlook VSTO Add-in, how can I know the list of folders shown by default in the Outlook? I mean, Inbox, Outbox, Sent Items, Deleted Items, etc. The ones that Outlook shows by default and make available to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean mail folders. Outlook shows all mail folders (`Mail.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olMailItem`) that are not hidden - `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` MAPI property must be missing or false (use `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10F4000B")`).

Now the order of the folders is a different matter...

Comment: ok, so i guess i need to iterate over all folders and get the ones that satisfy the condition Mail.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.OlMailItem and property PR_ATTR_HIDDEN == false? How can I get the list of all the folders I have to iterate over? Could you please show a code snippet?

Comment: Start with Store.GetRootFolder (returns MAPIFolder object) and iterate through the child folders in the MAPIFolder.Folders collection. Store obejct can come from Application.Session.DefaultFolder.